# mailing using microsoftonline

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I am trying to send email using following method. credentials are not given here for security. But they are correct.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mailTo = "testmail@testmail.com";
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("email@email.onmicrosoft.com", mailTo);           

        mail.Subject = "Test";
        mail.Body = "Blank Email";
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        // Set the StmpServer name. 
        SmtpClient mailSmtp = new SmtpClient("Smtp.mail.microsoftonline.com");

        // Smtp configuration            
        mailSmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@email.onmicrosoft.com", "********");            
        mailSmtp.Port = 587;          
        mailSmtp.Timeout = 30000;
        try
        {
            mailSmtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

but this is not working. "**Failur sending mail**" is the message of **SmtpException** which caught.

i have tried using `mailSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` before setting credentials. **EnableSsl** to **true**, **Deliverymethod** to **Network**. But nothing changed the situation.

Comment: there is no more to the error message than that?

Comment: i got this message in InnerException. `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.55.171.153:587`

Comment: Provide more Exception details here.

Comment: 'Unable to connect to the remote server' ... SocketErrorCode = `System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.TimedOut` NativeErrorCode = `10060`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ISP allows outgoing connections at port 25. If port 25 is closed, you will have this error.